# How we can replace space in string with some word(ex:- 'XXX') without using string library in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program without using string library in C which can replace the spaces in string with 'XXX'.
I have done this much but did not getting idea after this.

```
 char buff[100];
 int i;
 char *my_func(char *arr){
     for( i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++){
         if(arr[i]==' '){
             buff[i]='X';
             break;
         }
         else{
             buff[i]=arr[i];
         }
     }
     buff[i+1]='X';
     buff[i+2]='X';
     return buff;
 }
int main()
{
    char arr[]="This is my string";
    my_func(arr);
    printf("%s",buff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Output of above program is:ThisXXX

Comment: you are using break for exit the for loop. Exiting the loop you are just replacing the first space and not copying the remaining part of the array.

Comment: I was trying this way because i am unable to replace spaces with 'XXX'.

Comment: You will need two indexes, for instance `i` to explore `arr`, and `j` to write into `buff`. when you detector a space in `arr`, you have to insert 3 `X` in buff (in your `if`). You can remove `break` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track the indices for your source and destination buffers separately, since encountering a space in the source string will cause the resulting string to grow disproportionately.

Those character assignments should be inside inside the loop.

Don't forget to NUL terminate your destination buffer.

*Avoid global variables when possible.*

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *replace(char *dest, char *src) {
    size_t j = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; src[i]; i++) {
        if (src[i] == ' ') {
            dest[j++] = 'X';
            dest[j++] = 'X';
            dest[j++] = 'X';
        } else
            dest[j++] = src[i];
    }

    dest[j] = '\0';

    return dest;
}

int main(void) {
    char arr[] = "This is my string.";
    char buffer[256];

    replace(buffer, arr);

    printf("[%s] --> [%s]\n", arr, buffer);
}
```

Output:

```
[This is my string.] --> [ThisXXXisXXXmyXXXstring.]
```

Comment: as an addition I would consider `malloc()` ing buffer: `char *buffer = malloc(strlen(arr)*3 + 1);` will always be enough